# Can I use protractor not only for testing but for filling a form automatically, if not what can I do?

Tags: protractor

A friend of mine has to fill online forms every day, and she wonders if there is a way to make this things automatically because she has all the data in a separate file. I showed her protractor, so she asked me if it is possible to use protractor for filling these forms. I think that one is able to use protractor when owns the project, but I don't really know if it is possible to use it when not. If it is not possible to do it, what can I do. I mean what she can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases you could, but mostly no. Protractor only appears to work with websites built using AngularJS, however the website does not need to be served locally. The example on the [Protractor homepage](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) performs a test on the public/offical AngularJS website:

```
browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
```

From your own home computer, you can run automated Protractor/Jasmine tests (or other such things) on public websites built with AngularJS. However, you won't be able to perform a Google Search with this method for example, since http://www.google.com does not use Angular.

For more versatile browser automation, you could look at [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) for Firefox, or [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net) for Chrome. These allow you to write JavaScript which will run in your browser, on top of a particular website, to modify that website's appearance or behaviour.

One other possibility is to write some kind of full automation script, using Python or BASH/curl. Deconstruct the web forms, treat the website effectively like an API, and use HTTP POST to submit form content. However, this would only be effective if your friend uses a select few web forms since it would need to be heavily custom-designed for each form. Also, it would not allow her to manually interact with the website or enter any values. That said, it is probably the most universal and commonly used method of achieving the automation you speak of. Additionally, the website(s) your friend uses might even publish some kind of official documented API, which would make this process far easier.

Comment: I like the idea of using Python. She knows Python, and she likes it a lot. However, the limitation of not being allowed interacting manually could be a big problem. I will suggest her about Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey, but I guess she will choose the second option because she does not like Firefox. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey are mostly identical, so code written for one should work with both.

Comment: Actually you can use Protractor for non-angular sites. You just have to turn off synchronization for Angular, and manually use ExpectedConditions to wait for the page to load properly. However Protractor is not made for that so Greasemonkey might be better =)

Comment: @hankduan Ahh thanks, that explains why it wasn't working for me :)